# Error: No template found for XxxController#update, rendering head :no_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello i have the follow code working in development.

```
class SetupController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profile complete'
      redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:danger] = errors(current_user)
      redirect_to setup_users(current_user)
    end
  end
end

get 'setup' => 'setup#edit'
patch 'setup' => 'setup#update'
```

However in production I get the following error. The page doesn't do anything. It doesn't redirect. No flash. No nothing.

```
2017-04-09T01:32:16.299188+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SetupController#update as HTML
2017-04-09T01:32:16.299340+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9le9H2d1bjNgJyHQDXxuHarF0WOO3acl5jar9txe4Ws2ZaWuzmQ13kQG9HSce3RJ4HksZ5eCQyfuUZPwkDESxw==", "user"=>{"email"=>"joseph@netengine.com.au", "country"=>"AU"}, "commit"=>"Save", "username"=>"joey_knp"}
2017-04-09T01:32:16.357734+00:00 app[web.1]: No template found for SetupController#update, rendering head :no_content
2017-04-09T01:32:16.358169+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 204 No Content in 59ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
class SetupController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profile complete'
      redirect_url = user_profile_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:danger] = errors(current_user)
      redirect_url = setup_users(current_user)
    end
    redirect_to redirect_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

add like this way -

```
class SetupController < ApplicationController
  def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profile complete'
      redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:danger] = errors(current_user)
      redirect_to setup_users(current_user)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json
    end
  end
end
```

or you can simply add `render json: {}` or `render 'edit'` at the end of loop